# Reload specific controls after a child window closes

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, delegates, telerik

I have a C# web application using master page...content page...usercontrol that contains a radgrid. To edit a record in that radgrid I launch an custom edit form into a radwindow using a custom url set in the itemcreated event. The edit form contains various controls but at the end of the edit form I will have 2 textboxes and a button. If the user needs to change the values of those 2 textboxes they must click the button to open another .aspx form with usercontrol in a radwindow to perform various database operations to retrieve the new values. I am saving the 2 values into Session so they will be available across the application. My question is how can I implement a delegate to reload the values of just those 2 textboxes when I close the child form. I am not as up on delegates as I need to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about having the specific controls listen for the child window closed event?

before you launch the child window add this code:

```
childwindow.FormClosed += new EventHandler(child_Closed)
```

then have a class function like this:

```
void Form117_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      myControl.Text = Session["myControlText"];
      myControl2.Text = Session["myControl2Text"];
    }
```

Comment: That sounds what I am looking for. Would you happen to have an example?

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I did try something similar but I it seems that my Control is null when the parent loads see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363215/subscribing-to-an-event-of-a-ascx-of-another-ascx-in-a-different-window/8363330) for my updated code

Comment: Yuck.  Sounds like the radwindow is your problem.  :(  Any chance you can replace it or wrap it inside another class?